# Creating custom taxonomies but can't create new item, fields are gone

Tags: wordpress, post, custom-post-type

I've just created a new custom post type and custom taxonomies and linked it to the custom post type that I made. Problem is I can't add new item on custom taxonomies because fields are gone?

See Screenshot.

[click me for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rD0I.png)

Here's my code:

```
    function create_post_type_deals() {
  register_post_type( 'deals',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
       'name' => __( 'Deals' ),
       'singular_name' => __( 'deal' )
      ),

      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'deal'),
      'taxonomies' => array('tags', 'category', 'deal_type' ),
    )
  );
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_deals' );

//Register new taxonomy DEAL TYPE MC
function deals_init() {
    // create a new taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
        'deal_type',
        'deals',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Deal Type' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'deal-type' ),
            'capabilities' => array(
                'assign_terms' => 'edit_guides',
                'edit_terms' => 'publish_guides'
            ),
            'labels' => array(
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'deals_init' );
```

Comment: Please write your code example here

Comment: I've already edited it now Nikita Dudarev!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your capabilities.

Using

```
'capabilities' => array(
  'assign_terms' => 'edit_posts',
  'edit_terms' => 'publish_posts'
)
```

Will make it show correctly. I assume that your current capabilities aren't defined or something similiar. Double check you have set up the capabilities correctly.

Also, you are missing a lot of labels so I would recommend using this tool for custom taxonomies & custom post types: https://generatewp.com/taxonomy/

Comment: I've deleted the capabilities.. It works now. Thanks!